# Can you force an increase on the RAM an android device allocates to your application?

Tags: android, ram, allocation

I have been working on an app for quite some time, but it seems the first time it starts on a device (first ever, that is) it lags-a-lot. The second time however, it is smooth as butter. I suspect this is because the system adapts the RAM allocation after your first session, and I am wondering if I could override whatever is in charge of deciding how much RAM to allocate to my app? It's quite frustrating, and it seems like whatever i do just makes it worse. If there is no way to do this, are there any RAM heavy tasks that I can initiate the first time I start the app? Like, behind a splash screen or something. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> I suspect this is because the system adapts the RAM allocation after your first session

Android does not do this, to the best of my knowledge. All app processes start in the same state: as a fork of the zygote process.

> I am wondering if I could override whatever is in charge of deciding how much RAM to allocate to my app?

Not in terms of initial allocation, which for some reason seems to be your concern.

> are there any RAM heavy tasks that I can initiate the first time I start the app?

Not in general. Any that would exist would be specific to your app.

It would help if you would determine *exactly* where your problem lies:

- Make sure that you have `StrictMode` enabled and configured to yell at you when you do inappropriate stuff, like disk I/O, on the main application thread
- Use logging to narrow down where the lag is occurring within your code
- Given that logging, use method tracing to determine specifically what lines of code are slow, so you can attempt to reduce that work, move it to a background thread, etc.
- And so on

RAM rarely slows things down. If anything, RAM speeds things up (e.g., caching). Our problems with RAM come from running out of RAM and crashing.

Comment: Oh, alright. The source of my suspicion was the RAM graph in Android Studio going to it's limit, and increasing the ram allocation, or maybe garbage collecting. The second time the graph was always below the limit, so I thought the system had adapted. You have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @SimonBergmark: Presumably, your process was already running. Android allocates more system RAM as needed, but it will only release unused heap space back to the system during idle periods, and then mostly only Android 5.0+. Android does not immediately terminate your process when the user leaves the app. You can manually terminate the process from Android Studio (red square in the main toolbar) to confirm whether this explains what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is because some flaws on the code, i wold recomend you to use https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-memory.html (integrated in android studio), to detect where this memory leaks happens, also  use https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint.html (integrated in android studio) it will show you most common error (if present) on your code.